# How can I find Wither kill spots in the nether bedrock roof?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking for a wither kill station in the nether roof.

I have searched around for a bit and what I find is either dead websites (wither3x3 .net) or very long txt files (https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/4fn3ap/comment/d2antlo/, that directs to http://2c4.org/Nether3x3Bedrock.txt).

I tried going to look at some of the locations listed on the txt file, but they do not seem to correspond to good locations, so I suspect that the nether roof generation must have changed.

Is there a 1.19 tool to compute such locations, similar to what Chunkbase does for other things like locations of treasures/structures?

Comment: Apparently in [21w40a](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-21w40a) it was changed from being the same in every world: "Bedrock layers generate dependent on the world seed now"

Comment: @Plagiatus that's what I suspected. As I have the world seed (it's my own local SMP), is there a tool that allows finding such locations?

Comment: I am unaware of such a tool, but I have never tried to find one, either. So I'm hoping that if it exists, someone else knows about it and can post about it here. One alternative could be to take your world, the amulet editor and write a custom script that checks for this sort of generation starting from a specific position.